# a simple example for showing the use of Data Execution Prevention (DEP) security feature

Tags: .net, windows, security

I am finding it really hard to figure out why we need a DEP!

[Microsoft states](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/875352) this about DEP:

> The primary benefit of DEP is to help prevent code execution from data
>   pages.
>
> Typically, **code is not executed from the default heap and the stack**.
>   Hardware-enforced DEP detects code that is running from these
>   locations and raises an exception when execution occurs.
>
> Software-enforced DEP can help **prevent malicious code from taking
>   advantage of exception-handling mechanisms in Windows**.

What that means?

Can you give me a simple non-code example for this!

Comment: Sounds like a question that shouldn't be asked according to the FAQ: [What kind of questions should I not ask here? - You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on **actual problems that you face**.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: not an open ended question though..i am asking for an example.

Comment: So what **problem** do you have that you need an example?  And [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: googling,micro-sites.
actually most of the sites have no examples and microsoft's useless sites are more confusing than helping!

Comment: is it that the heap and stack section of memory give full permissions for a malicious program to execute!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say I am an attacker, and I have found a vulnerability which (solely) allows me to set EIP - the program counter - in your application.
The classic way to exploit this is to write a small code stub ('shellcode') and send it to your application as some parameter (so it might be put into the 'first name' field on a banking app, for example). Your application would store it in a stack (or heap) buffer, and I could then set EIP - using the vulnerably I found - to point to the start of this buffer. Voila, my code stub is executed, and your box is pwned :)

Using DEP, the CPU knows to reject attempts to execute this data, and you're a little bit safer.

It's a tad more complex than this in practice, but that's the gist of it. Does that make sense?